# How to connect to Mosquitto by using react-websocket

Tags: reactjs, websocket, mqtt, mosquitto

After `npm install react-websocket`

I'm trying to connect Windows Mosquitto(MQTT Broker server).

and then I set the websocket address in my react source, but cannot receive messages from Mosquitto, and also cannot publish any messages to Mosquitto server.

But it works in glassfish server which is run by Java.

I think Mosquitto and glassfish server are same websocket server, but it seems to be that there is difference between them.

Is there solution to connect Mosquitto Broker server by using react-websocket library?

**react-websocket library's version is 2.0.0
Mosquitto MQTT Broker server version is 1.5.4**

```
import Websocket from 'react-websocket'

export default class WebsocketInput {

  constructor(queue, onOpenCallback) {
    this.queue = queue
    this.websocket = new Websocket({
      url: process.env.REACT_APP_WEBSOCKET_ADDRESS,
      onMessage: function(data) {
        queue.offer(JSON.parse(data))
      },
      onOpen: function() {
        onOpenCallback()
      }
    })
    this.websocket.setupWebsocket()
  }

  sendMessage(msg) {
    this.websocket.state.ws.send(msg)
  }

  close() {
    this.websocket.shouldReconnect = false
    this.websocket.state.ws.close()
  }
}
```

Here is React code and I downloaded this from https://github.com/door2door-io/simulation-demo. I set the url 'ws://localhost:9001', but can't receive any messages in React app.

```
port 1883
protocol mqtt

listener 9001
protocol websockets
```

And this is part of mosquitto.conf file. I run the server by typing mosquitto -v -c mosquitto.conf, and I run mosquitto server in Windows CMD.
thanks

Comment: Please share the code you are using to publish/subscribe. Note that you are using 'MQTT over WebSockets'; an [MQTT](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/mqtt-v5.0.html) implementation is needed; its more complex than establishing a websocket connection and sending/receiving text. I would suggest using an MQTT library (examples include [mqtt.js](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js) and [paho-mqtt](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.javascript#readme)).

Comment: If you do not mind using ``mqtt.js`` I can share some code that worked for me.

Comment: I would be grateful if you share some code.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code; as previously noted you cannot just send/receive strings over the Websocket connection but need to implement the MQTT protocol (starting with a [CONNECT](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901033) packet). Searching for "react mqtt" should lead you to a number of examples (using an MQTT library).

Comment: #Brits I really appreciated to your aid.